# while (x !== null) results in error

Tags: javascript

I am using a third party calendar app that is throwing an error in Firefox that reads "**Permission denied to access property 'parentNode'**". In Safari I'm getting "**TypeError: 'undefined' is not any object (evaluating 't.parentNode')**". Here is my while loop. Note: *I did not write this code but I am attempting to fix it and failing.*

```
while (t.parentNode !== null) {
    if (t.id === this.divName) {                
        return true;
    }

    t = t.parentNode;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `t` is not `undefined` at the beginning of your loop?

Comment: This is what was happening in my particular case. I wrapped it in a if (t) { // } which seemed to fix the problem. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Chrome gives `ReferenceError: t is not defined`. Much clearer for debugging :-)

Answer (score 5):

You mean `while (t.parentNode)`.

At the root of the DOM, `parentNode` will be null, not an empty array.

Comment: I was testing out testing against .length property. I incorrectly left it in my code sample. Updated.

Comment: Try `while (t.parentNode)`; this will check for `undefined` too.

Comment: while (t.parentNode) { // stuff } still gives me the same error.

Comment: Your answer was correct, but I wasn't testing to see if t was null.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about Matt Kruse's calendar. I fixed the issue changing the line below  to your loop as none of the solutions showed in this thread worked for me.

The change was in line 49, just before the loop, where it says:

var t = e.originalTarget;

should be:

var t = e.target;

and that made dissapear the messages from firebug

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Matt Kruse's calendar if you look on the line immediately preceding the code you pasted it will say:

```
var t = e.originalTarget;
```

The fix that worked for me is to change this to:

```
var t = typeof e.originalTarget === 'undefined' ? e.srcElement : e.originalTarget;
```

Comment: I am using his calendar. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
while (t = t.parentNode) {
    if (t.id === this.divName) {                
        return true;
    }
}
```

see this (basic) [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VqCnm/)